# User with a pattern of completely incoherent answers

Tags: support, answers, specific-user, low-quality-posts

What to do about a user with a pattern of completely incoherent answers (as if produced by a random sentence generator): [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136547/flux-of-a-hemisphere/3136608#3136608), or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399522/on-the-absolutely-continuous-sign-measure-functions-and-borel-sigma-algebra/2399549#2399549),  for example?

I flagged three of more egregious examples: they have been deleted.  But I wonder what is the procedure for closing an account.

Comment: When you say that you *tagged* three answer, did you mean to say that you *[flagged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/flagging/info)* them? (Probably it might make the post more clear, although it seems like the most likely guess.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant "flagged".

Comment: @user539887 I have to admit that I am not sure what exactly is *incoherent* about these posts. I think that I am missing something. Could you elaborate on why you think this specific user is worth being discussed here on Meta?

Comment: @mrtaurho There is nothing incoherent in these *posts*.  As I mentioned in my post here on Meta, a user has a pattern of rambling *answers*. The moderators acted very quickly and deleted the stuff I mentioned in my post. But some other examples are still visible as of March 31, 2019, 7:25 GMT, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177348/fourier-series-sinn-pi-usage/2103490#2103490), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385650/find-the-absolute-maximum-and-minimum-given-constraint/2385763#2385763).

Comment: @user539887 : I think it is best to "stay tuned", because I also think that the occurence of robot-generated word-spaghetti is to be expected somehow similarly like the trolling in the usenet math-groups. Maybe it is not yet the case here although it looks much like, in my view. Perhaps setting up an archive of such observations/guesses would be a good idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see a pattern of problematic behavior of a user, flag a post by that user as "in need of moderator intervention" and describe the problem.

This applies to essentially any pattern of problematic behavior. (It's best to flag a post related to the pattern, but if this is impossible just flag any post by that user. Please, do flag a post though, and not a comment.)

Consistently, low-quality contributions indeed can be a reason for suspension of an account. When made aware of it moderators will investigate and evaluate the situation.

Comment: Thank you.  It worked so far: that user was last seen on March 30 at 17:25.